# Add Dropdown menu to TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have form where I collect data from client in flutter.
At the last 3 fields I want add dropdown menu with different choice to be done by the customers.
But I cant find how to add dropdown menu choice to the form flutter.
this is the screen shot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqJ1H.png)

the part of the code interested is:

````
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 193,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 14),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: '',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Color(0xFF1f2032),size: 17,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        hintText: '',
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 35.0),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Container(
                    width: 193,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 14),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: '',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Color(0xFF1f2032),size: 17,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        hintText: '',
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 35.0),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Container(
                    width: 193,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 14),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: '',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Color(0xFF1f2032),size: 17,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        hintText: '',
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 35.0),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ), ```
````

Comment: I think https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html is what you need...

Comment: check this article is may help  https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/09/flutter-drop-down-menu-list-example.html

Comment: I dont think so the DropDown menu can be a part of textField